# Airflow webserver not starting(first time)

Tags: airflow, amazon-rds, rhel

My environment is RHEL VM, Python 3.6, Postgres DB on AWS RDS.
I am a newbie starting to learn usage of Airflow.
I followed guidance from: https://medium.com/@klogic/introduction-of-airflow-tool-for-create-etl-pipeline-dc37ad049211

At **airflow init db** stage, I created a new admin user using command: FLASK_APP=airflow.www.app flask fab create-admin

Next step is, **airflow webserver -p 8080** but it's not working. The error it shows is:
[image]

From where are these 4 workers coming from? How to resolve this issue? I checked my postgres database and there are new tables added namely - 'job', 'dag' and 'dag_pickle'
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check memory available for your VM. Airflow starts 4 workers by default and they are pretty memory hungry (depends on your configuration). Increasing memory should help

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I increased the base VM memory from 2GB to 4 GB but I am still stuck with this issue. It's showing the same logs as before.

Comment: When I do 'airflow db init' it shows 'initialization done' and in next step 'airflow webserver' it's in indefinite loop of booting workers-workers timeout-workers exiting.

Comment: You need to look at logs in the system. Something is killing your workers but without logs it is impossible to tell what and why